# I have tried to install virtual env in Python 3.6 and I've followed all the instructions but it doesn't seem to work. Have I done something wrong?

Tags: python

I've tried with this command

```
-m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

yet it doesn't work... I don't know, I have never used the command prompt before so I am technically new to this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Are you using `python`, `python3`, or `py` as part of your command?